# How to make Python property object human-readable - Rendering it through Django templates

Tags: django, python-3.x, properties, django-templates

I have this property that should display the total price for each product, and I call it in my views and render it. On the rendered page, it just shows up as `<property object at 0x0000023CDA655048>` How am I supposed to make this human-readable? I know this is really simple, and I can't figure out how. I tried the following within my `cart.py` file that the class and property function belongs to:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.total_price


@property
def total_price(self):
    return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())
```

If I return it as a print statement, it returns none instead of an object, so maybe I am rendering it in the wrong place?
I called it in my `views.py` like:

```
    def get_cart(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    total = Cart.total_price
    return render(request, 'buylist/cart.html', {'cart':cart, 'total':total})
```

within a for loop, I rendered it for each item in my `cart.html` and called it like:

```
Total: {{total}}
```

I am expecting to see the human-readable total price for each product on each product's line, but instead I'm just seeing the actual property object. I'm sure it's something really simple I'm missing haha, but I've been stuck on this for a minute! If you could help, that would be awesome.

Comment: This is the same problem you had yesterday. `cart.total_price`, not `Cart.total_price`.

Comment: Yeah you're right! Thanks for pointing that out again. It will be the first thing I look for now haha. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use `cart.total_price` instead of `Cart.total_price`. I referenced the class function directly instead of the requested cart